# spring mvc hibernate restful (concurrency) issue

Tags: javascript, multithreading, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Recently I have encounter a problem with the web application. I'm using the spring mvc restful application together with hibernate as jpa.

The client could build a xml file using this format:

```
<SCCF>
    <registerSCCF>...</registerSCCF>
    ...
    <registerSCCF>...</registerSCCF>
</SCCF>
```

The web app will then mapping every data inside registerSCCF tag to a class and save it in the database.

Now I am suffering with the problem that when i test it using soapui and multithreading test, i always get the exception

> [ERROR] an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
>               org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in draft.persistence.entity.dcrm.CustomersNoneSSO entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

or

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous

or

> org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

Here is the service layer code:

```
@Transactional("dcrm")
public boolean postSCCFService(SCCFVO sccf){
    CustomersNoneSSO cns = new CustomersNoneSSO();
    cns.setAppid(sccf.getAppid());
    cns.setCustomer_name(sccf.getCustomer_name());
    cns.setCustomer_gender(sccf.getCustomer_gender());
    cns.setContact_mobile(sccf.getContact_mobile());
    cns.setContact_email(sccf.getContact_email());
    cns.setAddress_province(sccf.getAddress_province());
    cns.setAddress_city(sccf.getAddress_city());
    cns.setCustomer_address(sccf.getCustomer_address());
    cns.setCustomer_occupation(sccf.getCustomer_occupation());
    cns.setPurchase_brand(sccf.getPurchase_brand());
    cns.setPurchase_model(sccf.getPurchase_model());
    cns.setPurchase_date(sccf.getPurchase_date());
    cns.setPurchase_budget(sccf.getPurchase_budget());
    cns.setOwncar_selected(sccf.getOwncar_selected());
    cns.setOwncar_model(sccf.getOwncar_model());
    cns.setTestdrive_permission(sccf.getTestdrive_permission());
    cns.setMarketing_permission(sccf.getMarketing_permission());
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
    cns.setInsert_timestamp(t);
    cns.setUpdate_timestamp(t);
    cnsDao.makePersistent(cns);
}
```

if i set all the setter to static values like:

```
cns.setContact_email("test@test.test");
```

instead of using the value from the parameter, then the app runs well with the multithreading test.

There is the controller calls the service method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody SCCFResponseList getPostResults(@RequestBody SCCFVOList sccf){
    ...
    for(SCCFVO sccfvo : sccf.getSCCFVOList()){
        ...
        boolean result = sccfservice.postSCCFService(sccfvo);
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public class SCCFVOList {
```

And here is the request body class:

```
@XmlElement(name="registerSCCF")
public class SCCFVOList {
private Vector<SCCFVO> SCCFVOList = null;

public Vector<SCCFVO> getSCCFVOList(){
    return SCCFVOList;
}

public void setSCCFVOList(Vector<SCCFVO> SCCFVOList){
    this.SCCFVOList = SCCFVOList;
}

}
```

And here the dao

```
public class CNSDao extends GenericHibernateDAO<CustomersNoneSSO, Long> {}

public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable>
    implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;
private Session session;

SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public GenericHibernateDAO() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void setSession(Session s) {
    this.session = s;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    if (session == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Session has not been set on DAO before usage");
    return session;
}

public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T makePersistent(T entity) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    return entity;
}

public void makeTransient(T entity) {
    getSession().delete(entity);
}

...
}
```

There should be something wrong either the controller method or the service method. Still no idea what was wrong.

Comment: First I would expect the service to save everything or non, I wouldn't loop in the controller but that is me. Looks like you have a problem in your dao post the code.

Comment: This is a good point that the loop should take place in the controller. But they are indeed all saved in the database except a few when execption happened. I will post the dao anyway.

Comment: And there is your problem... NEVER *NEVER* **NEVER** (did I mention NEVER) store the session in a member variable... The `Session` isn't thread safe, you have have a single instance of the dao, now imagine what happens with multiple threads.... Remove the storing (and the setter!) and always use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: I was a little bit suprised because i used the generic dao pattern here https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects Somehow i changed the private to protected of the session variable. After set it back still got the same exception :( Do you mean I should use the session inside the CNSDao class?

Comment: As i mentioned NEVER use a instance variable to store the session! Remove the property, remove the setter and the getter should be nothing more the a call to `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. What do you thing happens with 100 threads all trying to set and use a session on a single instance of the dao? This would only work if the dao wouldn't be a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dao is flawed.

Your dao is a singleton, there is only one. The Hibernate `Session` object isn't thread safe and shouldn't be used across threads.

You have 1 dao, 2 threads, Thread one gets instance X1 of a session, Thread two resets it to instance X2 now suddenly they share the same session, not to mention Thread 1 might even be operating on 2 different sessions.

As I mentioned in the comments NEVER store the `Session` in an instance variable. Remove it.

```
public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public GenericHibernateDAO() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

Also I would suggest dropping this and instead use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) saves you the trouble of creating and maintaining your own generic dao. (You mention you use JPA, if the entities are annotated it should be quite easy to do).

Comment: You are amazing. I just edited the getSession() method as you suggested. It went perfect! And I am gonna dig into the Spring Data JPA later. lol